# collection.find() for 2 collections and pushing the information to a view - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to extract all documents from 2 collections using `collection.find()` and pushing all the information to an ejs view using `res.render` using mongoose (node.js).

My code:

```
var eduvents = {
    en: [],
    ar: []
};

Eduvent.find({}, function(err, allEduvents) {
   allEduvents.forEach(function(eduvent) {
       eduvents.en.push(eduvent);
   });
});

EduventAr.find({}, function(err, allEduvents) {
    allEduvents.forEach(function(eduvent) {
       eduvents.ar.push(eduvent);
    });
});

console.log(eduvents);
```

when this is executed, I get this:

```
{ en: [], ar: [] }
```

Shouldn't I get all the **Eduvent** and **EduventAr** queries in the *eduvent* variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because mongoose `find` is synchronous, your console will run instantly before the response from query is returned, hence its empty

You can do something like this if you want to stick with this `callbacks` approach

```
var eduvents = {
    en: [],
    ar: []
};

Eduvent.find({}, function(err, allEduvents) {
    allEduvents.forEach(function(eduvent) {
       eduvents.en.push(eduvent);
    });

    EduventAr.find({}, function(err, allEduvents) {
        allEduvents.forEach(function(eduvent) {
            eduvents.ar.push(eduvent);
        });
        console.log(eduvents);
    });
});
```

Another approach would be to use `async` `await` as mongoose already has support for `Promises`

> Using Async / AWAIT

```
async function GetEvents(){

    try {

        var eduvents = {
            en: [],
            ar: []
        };

        var allEvents = await Eduvent.find();
        // Here you can simply assign array to the `eduevents.en` if you are not altering anything from `allEduvents`
        eduvents.en = allEduvents;

        var otherEvents = await EduventAr.find();
        eduvents.ar = otherEvents;

        console.log(eduvents);

    } catch(err) {
        console.log("ERROR",err);
    }

}
```

Comment: only `save` `exec` in [mongoose are Promises. Queries are **not** a Promise but thenable](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises)

Comment: Yes Please. Show me the ```async``` ```wait``` approach.

Comment: I have added async await approach, take a look